# Export Keynote slides with looped video clips to Quicktime movie

Tags: keynote, quicktime

I have put a little video clip in my Keynote presentation, which loops back and forth while other animations beside it are running.

When I export my Keynote presentation to a Quicktime movie, the looping videoclip inside the Keynote presentation just doesn't loop in the exported Quicktime movie. Instead the video clip will just play one time from beginning to the end.

Is it possible to export slides with looped video clips inside Keynote to a Quicktime movie?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. One would assume if you record the presentation of a Keynote, all visuals would be recorded. Turns out it’s not.

I tried myself, and any Quicktime loop is only exported once. Bug? In the meantime, you could **modify your Quicktime move to play several times in a row**.

You can do this in [Quicktime Player 7](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3678) (everyone should have it), by selecting all (CMD-A), copying to the clipboard (CMD-C) and then pressing paste (CMD-V) several times in a row. Save the movie in place, it will be virtually the same file size. Hope this helps!